# Sending data to another component with (React Native Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to send basic data from Home.js component to details.js component.

My home.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableHighlight, Image, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'


function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVxGaxSSgi?indent=2')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                setIsLoading(false)
                setDataSource(responseJson)

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error)
            });

    })
    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
            <FlatList
                data={dataSource}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details',{text:'alperen'})} underlayColor="white">
                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            <View style={styles.div}>
                                <View style={styles.inlineDiv}>
                                    <Image source={{ uri: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/900&#x2715700/?fruit' }} style={styles.pic} />
                                    <Text>{item.name}, {item.about}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>


                }
                keyExtractor={({ _id }, index) => _id}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pic: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    div: {
        shadowColor: "#fff",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 1,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.20,
        shadowRadius: 50,
        elevation: 0,
        marginBottom: 10

    },
    inlineDiv: {
        padding: 5,

    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});
```

This is my details.js component

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'


function DetailsScreen( navigation ) {
  useEffect(() => {
    alert(navigation.text)

  })
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text></Text>

    </View>
  );
}

export default DetailsScreen
```

I want to go to the other page and at the same time I want to send and print the data. This code is currently returning undefined. How Can I send data ? Probably I can use props but I don't know usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending data operation is success but details page is not working. I looked 'react-navigation documentation ' (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html). There is a keyword ('route') we have to use it.

```js
function DetailsScreen({ route }) {
  const { text } = route.params;
  useEffect(() => {

    var a = JSON.stringify(text)
    alert(a)
  })
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text></Text>

    </View>
  );
}
```

I tried this code and its working success.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function DetailsScreen( navigation ) {
  useEffect(() => {
    alert(navigation.text)

  })
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text></Text>

    </View>
  );
}
```

to

```
function DetailsScreen({navigation}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    alert(navigation.state.params.text)

  })
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text></Text>

    </View>
  );
}
```

And try

Comment: It's not working. I wrote alert(navigation.state.params.text) but emulator give an error. (undefined its not an object evaluating 'navigation.state.params')

Answer (score 0):

In first screen

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details',{item})} underlayColor="white">
```

In next screen you can get data

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.item
```

Example:

```
<Image source={this.props.navigation.state.params.item.img}/>

<Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.item.text}</Text>
```

Comment: Unfortunately It's not working. I get an error. Although I write this.props.navigation.state.params.item.text program said Undefined its not ann object evaluating  '_this.props not '